Solana Sending Transaction Error: -32002 aka processing Instruction error
I am trying to send Solana transactions, but I am getting the following error Failed to send buy transaction: ReasonTransaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xbbf Result: Error:-32002 Result: Reason:Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xbbf. I looked up the -32002 error code up on Solana's site and it states This is the preflight check error which means that the transaction you're sending has errors, you'll need to double check the params, signature, etc.
Now I was able to send an ATA transaction just fine but then when I went to send the actual transaction it fails. The ATA transaction used the same associatedTokenAddress, _wallet.Account, mintKey, and _wallet.Account.PublicKey so I know those are correct. I also checked my balance first and I have more than the calculated maxSolLamports even after considering fees. Does anyone know the possible cause of this error?
private const ulong BUY_DISCRIMINATOR = 16927863322537952870;

                double tokenPrice = token.VirtualSolReserves / token.VirtualTokenReserves;
                double tokensToBuy = solToSpend / tokenPrice;
                ulong tokenAmountLamports = (ulong)(tokensToBuy * TradeTokenData.TokenLamports);
                ulong maxSolLamports = (ulong)(solToSpend * TradeTokenData.SolLamports * slippage);

                byte[] buyData = new byte[24];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(BUY_DISCRIMINATOR), 0, buyData, 0, 8);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(tokenAmountLamports), 0, buyData, 8, 8);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(maxSolLamports), 0, buyData, 16, 8);

                Form1.DebugMessages.Add($"Buying Rn TokenPrice:{tokenPrice} TokensToBuy:{tokensToBuy} LamportAmount:{tokenAmountLamports} MaxSolLamparts:{maxSolLamports} " +
                    $"VirtualSol:{token.VirtualSolReserves} VirtualTokens:{token.VirtualTokenReserves}");

                TransactionInstruction buyInstruction = new TransactionInstruction 
                {
                    ProgramId = PUMP_PROGRAM_KEY.KeyBytes,
                    Keys = new List<AccountMeta>
                    {
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(PUMP_GLOBAL_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(PUMP_FEE_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(mintKey, false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(new PublicKey(token.BondingCurve), false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(new PublicKey(token.AssociatedBondingCurve), false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(associatedTokenAddress, false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(_wallet.Account.PublicKey, true),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(SYSTEM_PROGRAM_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(SYSTEM_TOKEN_PROGRAM_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(SYSTEM_RENT_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(PUMP_EVENT_AUTHORITY_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(PUMP_PROGRAM_KEY, false),
                    },
                    Data = buyData
                };

                Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                transaction.Add(buyInstruction);
                transaction.FeePayer = _wallet.Account.PublicKey;
                transaction.RecentBlockHash = recentBlockhash;

                transaction.Sign(_wallet.Account);
   
                var sendResponse = await rpcClient.SendTransactionAsync(transaction.Serialize(), skipPreflight: false); //, Commitment.Processed
                if (!sendResponse.WasSuccessful)
                {
                    Form1.DebugMessages.Add($"Failed to send buy transaction: Reason{sendResponse.Reason} Result:{sendResponse.Result} Error:{sendResponse.ServerErrorCode} Result:{sendResponse.Result} Reason:{sendResponse.Reason}");
                    throw new Exception($"Failed to send buy transaction: Reason{sendResponse.Reason}");
                }

Also when should one use Processed over Finalized when sending transactions what are the pros and cons of each when sending transactions?
